# How can you deallocate no-longer-needed NSLayoutConstraint objects that were programmatically created, to avoid a memory leak?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, weak-references

Something I find odd is once you create a constraint, the view hangs onto it forever, even if you explicitly remove it from the view's constraints collection (or set it's `isActive` to false which does so implicitly and what you should be doing since iOS 8 anyway.) This is regardless of if you yourself are hanging onto the reference, meaning if you let go of an inactive constraint, you have a memory leak... at least until the view itself is deallocated.

Worse, if you're hanging onto that constraint with a weak var, after the view is deallocated, instead of the weak var going to nil as one would expect, instead, if you try to access it, you outright crash.

Here's some Playground code to demonstrate the above.

```
weak var view = UIView()
print(view ?? "No view")
// Prints 'No view' since the view is created, then instantly deallocated.

var view2:UIView? = UIView()
weak var constraint = view2!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
print(constraint ?? "No constraint")
// Prints '<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003e0c140 UIView:0x7faa875079f0.width == 100   (inactive)>'
// This isn't expected since nothing should be holding the reference.

constraint?.isActive = false // Technically already false, but just checking
print(constraint ?? "No constraint")
// Prints '<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003e0c140 UIView:0x7faa875079f0.width == 100   (inactive)>'

view2!.removeConstraint(constraint!) // Again, technically not in here, but being explicit
print(constraint ?? "No constraint")
// Prints '<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003e0c140 UIView:0x7faa875079f0.width == 100   (inactive)>'

view2 = nil // This is the only thing that kills the constraint, but...
print(constraint ?? "No constraint") // This results in an outright crash
```

That last line resulted in...

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

So how does one properly clean up constraints that are no longer needed?

Comment: You should not call removeConstrain directly since iOS 8

Comment: Yup!  I know that.  But I'm trying to prove no matter what you do, something is holding onto that constraint.  I can't figure out how to deallocate it once it's no longer needed, hence giving me the leak, at least until the view disappears, and even then, there's the issue with the weak ref causing a crash instead of giving you nil as one would expect.  That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe Did you tried this outside of Playground?

Comment: Yes, same result.  Something else interesting, the editor shows a warning on the very first line (`weak var view = UIView()`) saying `Instance will be immediately deallocated because variable 'view' is 'weak'` but does *not* show that same warning for `weak var constraint = view2!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)` although I'm assuming that's because the latter is a function that the compiler can't be sure if something else is holding a reference (which apparently is the case), whereas the former is an initializer so it can.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe I think setting constraint.isActive = false shouldn't deallocate it, it's still attached to the UIView. It's adding the constraint to the UIView constraint list, but why do you assume it's should be deallocated? In your second example, where the UIView is not weak, it'll will only get deallocated once you went out of the function scope (assuming you haven't added it to the other UIView tree or assigned it). As I see, it's doing exactly what it should

Comment: Couple things there... your point that the view is still hanging onto the constraint is the problem I'm calling out. Apple's own documentation says a non-active constraint will be removed from the `constraints` collection so the view is hanging onto it somewhere else, meaning if *you* aren't hanging onto a ref yourself, a constraint that goes inactive becomes a memory leak as long as the view sticks around since you can't get back to it.  Plus, if you have a weak ref to it, and the view *does* go out of scope, you get a crash, not `nil` as one would expect from a weak ref. That's the issue.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe Agreed about the doc, as for me, in real-world scenarios, I find my self tweaking the isActive true/false for animation, etc', without the need to re-add it. I'll try to debug it, but from my point of view, it's natural behavior with misleading docs, but that's just me. Will update if I find anything

Comment: Also, clarifying your comment "It's adding the constraint to the UIView constraint list," is incorrect.  Again, per the docs, it is *not* added to the collection until it is set active. Even so, something *else* in the view is hanging onto it, and that's the part you can't get to.  Basically, once you create a constraint, whether active or not, it will exist for as long as the view does and there's no way to 'clean it up' even if it's no longer needed.